# Open text file as input to textblob

Tags: python, readfile, textblob

I am trying to use textBlob with a text file input.

All examples I found online were of input in this sense:

```
wiki = TextBlob("Python is a high-level, general-purpose programming language.")
wiki.tage
```

I tried this:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
file=open("1.txt");
t=file.read();
print(type(t))
bobo = TextBlob(t)
bobo.tags
```

The code I tried did not work.

Comment: How exactly did the code *not work*?

Comment: What was the problem or error ?

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 572: ordinal not in range(128). @Backtrack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic [Unicode issue](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#1)

Use

```
import sys  

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Then read the file

In this way you can use `UTF-8` encoding/decoding format

**this is outdated for Python 3.X**

Comment: it did work thanks a lot but there is something weird, when i first ran it after importing sys there was no output i tried to take down all lines related to your code after first run and it worked there is something about the reload function i don't understand underlying technology , if there is an explanation can you please enlighten me? @Backtreack

Comment: Outdated answer for Python 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into Unidecode.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode

`from unidecode import unidecode
...
bobo = TextBlob(unidecode(t))`

Answer (score -1):

For Python3 guys:

```
import sys  
from importlib import reload
reload(sys)  
sys.getdefaultencoding() # use this for Python3
from textblob import TextBlob
url ='filename.txt'
file=open(url)
t=file.read()
print(type(t))
bobo = TextBlob(t)
bobo.tags
```

Comment: There is no need to get default encoding for Python 3.x versions